# Get leading series expansion term?

Tags: functions, function-construction, series-expansion

Given a function `f[x]`, I would like to have a function `leadingSeries` that returns just the leading term in the series around `x=0`. For example:

```
leadingSeries[(1/x + 2)/(4 + 1/x^2 + x)]
```

> `x`

and

```
leadingSeries[(1/x + 2 + (1 - 1/x^3)/4)/(4 + x)]
```

> `-(1/(16 x^3))`

Is there such a function in Mathematica? Or maybe one can implement it efficiently?

**EDIT**

I finally went with the following implementation, based on [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll)'s answer:

```
lds[ex_,x_]:=( (ex/.x->(x+O[x]^2))/.SeriesData[U_,Z_,L_List,Mi_,Ma_,De_]:>SeriesData[U,Z,{L[[1]]},Mi,Mi+1,De]//Quiet//Normal)
```

The advantage is, that this one also properly works with functions whose leading term is a constant:

```
lds[Exp[x],x]
```

> `1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129283/defining-a-function-via-pattern-matching-with-seriesdata

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 1**

*Updated to eliminate SeriesData and to not return additional terms*

Perhaps you could use:

```
leadingSeries[expr_, x_] := Normal[expr /. x->(x+O[x]^2) /. a_List :> Take[a, 1]]
```

Then for your examples:

```
leadingSeries[(1/x + 2)/(4 + 1/x^2 + x), x]
leadingSeries[Exp[x], x]
leadingSeries[(1/x + 2 + (1 - 1/x^3)/4)/(4 + x), x] // TeXForm
```

> x
>
> 1
>
> $-\frac{1}{16 x^3}$

One more example:

```
leadingSeries[x^100 (1/x + 2 + (1 - 1/x^2)/4)/(4 + x), x] // TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{x^{98}}{16}$

This last example shows that `leadingSeries` works even when the leading term has a very high order. Using something like `Series[expr, {x, 0, 1}]` will not get the leading order, although it does return something that would be useful as a stepping stone towards the answer.

**Update 2**

*Updated to support arbitrary expansion points*

Here is a version for arbitrary expansion points:

```
leadingSeries[expr_, {x_, x0_}] := Normal[
    expr /. 
        x -> Series[x, {x, x0, 1}] /.
        Verbatim[SeriesData][a__, {b_, ___}, c__] :> SeriesData[a, {b}, c]
]
```

For example:

```
leadingSeries[Gamma[x],{x,Infinity}]//TeXForm
```

> $\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} e^{x \left(-\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right)}$

Comment: This is amazing! Simple and powerful. Thank you!

Comment: The only trouble is with things that start with a constant though... `Exp[x] /. x -> (x + O[x]^2)`. But it should be easy enough to catch these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Those using recent versions of Mathematica (12.1 or later, I believe) can achieve this with the built-in function `Asymptotic`

```
examples = {(1/x + 2)/(4 + 1/x^2 + x),
   Exp[x], (1/x + 2 + (1 - 1/x^3)/4)/(4 + x)};

Asymptotic[examples, x -> 0]
(* {x, 1, -(1/(16 x^3))} *)
```