# Factor by a specific literal (i.e factor by $s^N$ a transfer function)

Tags: control-systems, factorization

I've found the closed loop transfer function but I want to know the order of it. So, the idea is to factor the denominator by the highest exponent of s to get an expression like this one:
$$
l(s)=g(s)r(s)=k \frac{b_ms^m+b_{m-1}s^{m-1}+\dots+1}{s^N(a_{n-N}s^{n-N}+a_{n-N-1}s^{n-N-1}+\dots+1)}
$$

I tried collect, factor terms but none of them seem to work for my purpose.

```
Collect[FullSimplify[(3.72 10^9 s - 5.73 10^6 s^2 + 57904 s^3 + 
     2.79 10^11)/((s + 64.4) (270 s + s^2 + 246193) (170 s + s^2 + 
       37812))], s]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for the leading term of the series expansion of your polynomial around the expansion point 0. One idea is given in my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148478/45431) to [Get leading series expansion term?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148476/45431):

```
expr = (3.72 10^9 s-5.73 10^6 s^2+57904 s^3+2.79 10^11)/((s+64.4) (270 s+s^2+246193) (170 s+s^2+37812));
expr /. s -> s + O[s]^2 //TeXForm
```

> $0.465386-0.00362407 s+O\left(s^2\right)$

Here is another example:

```
expr = (1 + s + s^2)/(s^3(1+s)(1+s^2)(1+s^3));
expr /. s -> s + O[s]^2 //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{s^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^2}\right)$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with that notation $O(s^2)$. In your example there, when it appears $O(s^2)$ does it mean the leading coefficient is $s^2$?